# Алгоритм установки ежедневных задач

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, sqlite, архитектура

Писал ежедневник, в котором выставляются задачи на день. Задачи хранятся в БД по в таблице со структурой: "ид" "дата" "текст задачи".

Есть база данных одиночных задач, а есть "Ежедневные" "Еженедельные" и.т.д.
Для таких я выделил новую сущность и объединяю запрос с "задачами на день" и "ежедневными".

Вопрос: Например после выполнения ежедневной задачи юзер выставляет ее как "Выполнено", и в этот день она больше не отображается.. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У задачи завести поле со временем следующей сработки. После того как юзер пометит как выполнено, посчитать и проапдейтить дату следующей сработки.

Comment: А если юзер ,например ,забудет ее пометить? 
Тогда на следующий день она не проапдейтится... Что делать тогда?

Comment: Тут надо исходить из полного use case для юзера. Можно хранить дату последней проверки, при запуске приложения выбирать все события у которых сработка позже этой даты, далее - напоминать о пропущенных и апдейтить дату.

Answer (score 0):

Завести новую таблицу, поле булен, чтобы менять значение на тру когда задание сделано, и написать функцию которая будет сбрасывать на фолс ровно В 00:00